# Conditional type based on generics types with entry properties check

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I create a function who take an argument with two architecture. I do not enforce rules to give user flexibility which is my headache now . Anyway.

I want to check if the entry has a function in first level. For example:

```js
//  Function in first level

const entry = {
  data: 10,
  upload:() => {},
  otherData: {},
  download: () => {}
}

// Function in deep level
const entry = {
  photo: {
   total: 10,
   upload: () => {}
  },
  videos: {
    total: 10,
    upload:() => {}
  }
}
```

If Typescript found a function at first level, I want it to return the type "slice" even if function are also present in deep level. As soon as it finds the function in first level, it should stop checking and return "slice".

If no function is present at the first level, it should return "group". No need to check other levels.

**Note**: the return should be either `slice` or `group` not an union `slice | group`

`slice` if a function is present at first level otherwise return `group`

The most closer solution to pass all my test case except one, was to reverse my check like this

```js
type GetType<S, k = keyof S> = S[k & keyof S] extends Exclude<S[k & keyof S],Function> ?  "group" : "slice"
```

Works fine but fail with an empty object as property and return `group`

```js
// ❌ This fail and give group as type. Expected type is slice 
const entry = {
  data: {} // empty object,
  upload: () => {}
}

// ✅ This works and give slice as type as Expected 
const entry = {
  data: any value // empty object,
  upload: () => {}
}
```

So yes, we can just find a way exclude `{}`. And that lead to all problem. Maybe I am tired and i can't see well . Anyway, I need a fresh eye to help me.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwBVwQDwGUA0UDWUC8OEIA9gGZRoB8+FA2rgGSEnloC6UEAHsBAHYATAM5QAolwDGAGwCuA1GnpQm2ImQpsMAMRl8JwAJbE+1APxQoAIgDmAJ2IywlqAC4rQqQYkRLAWABQARLGQsBQpAa2oWie3jQA3gEWFgIAhsCpbvEAvhhJyY5uABQAlHjUOVAB2QFBIWFCEMGCMV7QBIn+yVBpGW4AjAAMeV3JxMAAFhC2WfndFoVQpeVQOXNQueuLyxU1oxbVtf7NoVCTkQKtcR3r1nez+-OkAgMATFjWxWW765uPvZlVutuqRdBIvvgKkd5sk9t0-t1tt9Vns9nU+KdSA5bJMru0gY87p8USNugCHjCLKC9BCVp1gbDfqSCmAvnTUUcTmEIlFgDB7I4Erd7lB+u91uSCZTwmDaVDAo94UyJelUq8KZTqeCliVIQSGRY4bCsIcFVyoI1mgJ+Q4wELCSKcsyUqqNTCtXL9YrGY8EckAeqpZrZTq9fTvYamVV-GiFejMZForEIAAlCBCGRSYBuOCIZAoUCQdQ8pNtSgAbigAHoq1BADLkZ2QFomDikAigACNoB42pz6hamsZLsm0xmszn4EhIAXkOpLUO8RXq7XAKDkjcgUAMIh73gAdFAAJJhLdQYK2WxNYB9jFhc62YdtUeZ7OwSf5wsQdR3h-eJc1qBrh+m7bsm+5HsBp7EOel7Xpi2K4iO6bPhOebTh+xbwRMi6Vv+DZAUILaZu2XYWsm0bxtyiZ8gKYBPuOr6oag6HkCW1G2n+q7rtAJ52LaYHHiIZ4XvosENIOgg2o4dEvrmU5MbO5DzhJNFLsuAFcRBvGOPxEFCTBCpAA)

Comment: It seems your first object's type is being inferred as `{ data: {}, uploader: () => void }`, but in TypeScript the type `{}` doesn't mean "any object". Rather, it basically means "any value where attempting to access a property won't throw an error" - that is, anything but `null` or `undefined`. Usually, it's a type that should be avoided. Do you expect this sort of inference to happen in practice? Or would you expect variables to have more explicit types, e.g. `const entry: CustomType = ...`?

Comment: The type of the entry is not explicit. It can be `{data: {value: "..."}, someFunc}`, `...whatever` or `{items: [], someFunc}`. So the entry type is unknown. But we know that it will contain functions at firstLevel or second level. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want a type that only cares about a subset of the properties of an object type, then a mapped type to filter that down is usually what you want.

In general avoid type comparisons of large, complex object types is good, and you should compare more atomic bits. This is because there's a lot that could be a tiny bit different that's hard to debug.

So I propose a more verbose but easier to get right strategy. First find all properties that are functions, and then check to see if any were found.

So step 1:

```
type KeysWithFunctions<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown
            ? K
            : never
}[keyof T]
```

This returns a type that is a union of property names that are functions. If there are no properties that match, then a union with no members is just `never`.

So:

```
type A = { a: 123, b: () => void, c: () => boolean } // 'a' | 'b'
type B = { a: 123 } // never
```

Now `GetType` is very simply a check for `never`.

```
type GetType<T> =
    KeysWithFunctions<T> extends never
        ? 'group'
        : 'slice'
```

Which I think does what you want:

```
type A = GetType<{ data: {}, upload(): void }>
//   slice

type B = GetType<{ data: {} }>
//   group

type C = GetType<{ data: {}, nested: { data2: 20, fn: () => void } }>
//   group
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDqBLYALAYgVwHYGNgUB7XBAHgBUA+KAXigG8BYAKCg6gG0YoVcoAa3jEAZlEoBdAFxtO8iT0lQIAD2ARcAEwRQAFADojAQwBOAcwTSoeQbmIB3XF0kBKerVv2nchX4D8sL5+8ta4EABuEKZsAL5cwiBiEpJsbKCQUADiEMCU4BBUtHTBsPDIaFh4hCRkRSrqmjpQ4VEx7CGBAOTmpsTYYF2loVBdCAA2KPgQQ6zpBVAAgvTZufmQ5IxQWsbAxtYAjAAMADQ2YOPExlp6rtYRxChaULHUbAD075wAev5prBloAAhFY5PIFTbbXb7KDHF5vVifH5-OYAhYAYVBawhWx2e0OpxaEAQGi01lx0IATNZKYTRLhrLcPFAHk8XvCPl8OL9-mx8KQSVBRChTCSAMqTaYrFgdDh4mGMWInUoDRmuOi0RVQOL-flkYBQBAQPVaCVTaAMGXyeUE5WyqDEDDRcnDTiq-TqzWxUpKlVgNUapje+061F6wUYEWmyUWpilcwJl32+SiMmwylncwBr0+u3W6FJkJC6pq5ky10cYPyX32923QOK0N8gUG0T9UwYM1Sy3xxNBvOcG1x5OcUQlj1l-5FqucGvyOueoNN1jh1siklZPoDaW9rPpgdygvDotjgilhtTkIzysHqF7anHkKn-DnzWXvzXl5nZerw3G0haJu-RgDu9oJnuiq3kOVpPuOTIXqi065qU8oPjBfjPq+w4Vi8ubaqwwa8qwWjGuMZjQL+wqisAXYQAASsS2DjMA1hgushSAskVHijG1AANxQEigAy5FAgKGug-TjM8ABG0ATOa-wkfgZGmBRLZ-iatEMQgTEsas4IbJx4hGppvECUigCg5KJCwoLo8nTAYUAAJIGrZUD8qYqmEIppHke56mRqY0bmtpumsdihkFMkgXBdM-GCV8VliW59kQI5Ll8LoHlecAPnKX5lHtp2Mahcx4UGRxUXiG22AdugtHxcJ1mZAgElMTJckxvhbBKSpan6kK67AEBAylXpbEQkZg3USNYCNYlzXQG5vTAelrlZcQnnGrlqK9QV6kmQBs1jeV7HkFNh3aLN8UJVASU2boK0DGtmX+Vt3mokAA)

Comment: Now `GetType` is really simply a check for never. Thanks for the answer. This line open my mind and remove my headache. Because i had done something like this

`type OnlyFunctions<S> = ....

type GetTypes<S, K = keyof S> = K extends OnlyFunctions<S> ? "slice" : K & "group";
`
doing `K & "group"` create a never. I did not then checked for never .

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Mark Hana in comment,

> TypeScript the type {} doesn't mean "any object". Rather, it basically means "any value where attempting to access a property won't throw an error"

which means:

```
type EqualsTrue = ((() => void) | {}) extends {} ? true : false
// or more precisely
type EqualsTrue2 = Function extends {} ? true : false
```

It is very weird but that's what stands in our way. However the other way around is not true! And we can use that:

```
type EqualsFalse = {} extends Function ? true : false
```

Let's make a utility type, it's practically a filter function, that filters out the Function types from the input union.

```
type CheckExtends<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never
// usage:
type TypeArgs = {} | (() => void) | number | (() => boolean)
type TypeVal = CheckExtends<TypeArgs, Function>
//   ^? type TypeVal = (() => void) | (() => boolean)
```

Now we can put the value union, the `S[keyof S]` part into this filter, can get either all the functions type, or `never`. With this knowledge, the answer is obvious:

```
type GetType<S> = CheckExtends<S[keyof S], Function> extends never ? "group" : "slice"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwXARg6BeKAKAdPuAJwHMBnALijgDsQBtAXQEooMA+K2gWAChRJYACwgBjANYBRAB7AI1ACakAPABUANFACqHLCqgQZcxVqgB+KHsrUIANwiFe-aAHEIwFeAhKAyjqGjJQwVlbzoxCBAAewAzKG8GDXgkVHQOA1lgqGs7QjMoACJiQkiAVzB8qEp80gQASxEIfN5eEUjqUmAoaNrCDu86htYoAG9eKHGoeThgOEphgF81MYmyymwWdhGoed4dnha2jqhSUTb5fvrMEeXxqZnKAEYABiWeCahI4GFCOZv3qFWOA2HGG2z+iz+gPWrBBYP2PD2rXanS+PXOAyuozeE2IuN+2P+XXkjwATBpiGtgVs9u8IQTJtNZtd6e9oiVqCJKTDmX9aeDXu8oVTQXs9gdkV1SoQvhdBlgse9cRSRnT3ncmQrCV12ZygdysbyJjSjQKVmAuZsRbtmjwkUdur1gM5imUhprxkrSabboz8VrtRyLSCbf7jeNVRN1SS-Vq2YG9ZaQ1qw9tXmLbYdOickfJnaUwG6-p6Vd6Gfdmf647roYn4aH+X8ozHCVWgzyWUaGwibTanFBgA8hq53J4lE4Yl0en0MWwANy8AD0C4mAD1TI5PP2SUO3B5IGPPBPs2dZRA54vl+M1xuBMAAMw7kf78exVGEdGXc88Jer9d8TfAAALI+e5eC+kolNKginl+P5Xn+fbAAArCBo7gQ6HR5mUsGXlA17-reABsqHPoesTHgoWFgDhv5AA)